# No scroll on absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My html pseudocode looks like that:

```
  <div>
    <VideoAnimation />
    <div className="under-animation">
      // a lot of content goes here
    </div>
  </div>
```

The thing is that VideoAnimation component has absolute positioning and takes height of 100vh (it must be that way). Because of this is taken out of the flow of document. Under-section should go just after the animation (so it mimics relative positioning behaviour) so I decided to give it absolute position as well - it begins at top: 100vh. But this causes something unexpected to me, ie. I cannot scroll thru the page anymore. I can take a right scroll bar and scroll it but cannot use it on my mousepad. Issue does not exist on relative positioning. Thanks!

My VideoSection component looks like that:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="video__container">
        <video autoPlay muted className="myVideo">
          <source
        src="https://res.cloudinary.com/da0fiq118/video/upload/c_scale,h_600/v1538825517/animation.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default VideoAnimation;
```

And scss file:

```
.video {
  &__container {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

.myVideo {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  left: auto;
  max-width: none;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

@supports (transform: translateX(-50%)) {

  .myVideo {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }

}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9){

  .myVideo {
    max-width: 100vw;
    min-width: 100vw;
    width: 100vw;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9){

  .myVideo {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }

}
```

The goal was to have animation in the center in every resolution with full viewport height, that's why I used absolute positioning and then manipulated its values.

Comment: Put the actual code and all the CSS in place and we can give better answers.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot use it? Does the scroll bar not recognize that you are holding down the left mouse button on it? Does the bar not move while dragging? Does it move but the content doesnt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update:

With the new example code, I'm not seeing a reason you need to keep the video absolute, would 100vh and 100vw not suffice?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyCormack/z1xp9rw2/5/)

#### Original post:

All of your content is absolute positioned, there is no content left in the normal document flow to give the body height to scroll.

Without knowing why the `VideoAnimation` element "must be" absolute, the easiest solution would be to not give the `under-animation` div position absolute and instead simply give it a top margin of 100vh. This keeps the element within the document flow and still compensates for the video's space.

To be clear, this is also a less than desirable setup that could run into issues if things change, but without more information it's the easiest one to give.

Comment: _"there is no content left in the normal document flow to give the body height to scroll."_ Note just because they have a position of absolute does not mean they do not affect the scrolling of a document. OP gave the second element a top that would put that element outside the viewport and thus create a scroll if the relative content didnt, for example http://jsfiddle.net/s9gyd8oc/

Comment: That's true, in that case I cannot replicate the situation in the question, since absolute should work. The cause must be something else.

Comment: @AndyCormack I updated the question in order to give better explanation why I chose to use absolute positioning on my animation. I believe that is only way to have my animation centered in every resolution and have it full viewport height as well.

Comment: See my edited answer, was this what you were looking for?